# MySQL Multi Master Replication

Tags: replication, mysql-5.7

I have 4 servers running MySQL 5.7 in total , servers 1,2,3 each has single database on them For example:

```
Server 1 has the DB x_1
Server 2 has the DB x_2
Server 3 has the DB x_3
```

Server 4 has 3 databases in it:

```
x_1
x_2
x_3
```

What i want to achieve is master to master replication between the 3 servers and server 4 each to his own database:

```
Changes in x_1 in server 4 or server 1 will replicate both ways
Changes in x_2 in server 4 or server 2 will replicate both ways
.
.
.
```

Appreciate any guidance to the correct way to achieve this (*Note: I already know about multi source replication single slave and multiple masters but i am not sure if it can be used here*)

Answer (score 0):

You have to build two replication setups:

- from masters 1, 2 and 3 to the slave 4 in the `multimaster` config
- from master 4 to slaves 1, 2 and 3 in the plain replication config

Caveats:

- each instance of mysql should have an unique `server_id` to tell events originators
- multimaster masters 1, 2 and 3 should use `binlog_do_db` directive to restrict the set of databases being replicated (until you want to populate ALL the DB's like `mysql.*` across the whole setup):
  `binlog_do_db = x_?  # on each server 1, 2 and 3`
- mysql 4 as a master needs a restriction for replicated databases too:
  `binlog_do_db = x_1,x_2,x_3`
- plain replication from the single master to three slaves means the shared master  `binlog` will contain the events from all the databases mentioned in the `binlog_do_db` directive. So be ready that `relay` files will be about three times bigger than required for a single DB.
- also you have to restrict the replication on each slave to the proper DB:
  `replicate_do_db = x_? # on 1, 2 and 3`
- you have to turn on the binloging on all the servers
- you have to `CHANGE MASTER 's1'...`, `CHANGE MASTER 's2'...` and `CHANGE MASTER 's3'...` on the server 4
- you have to `CHANGE MASTER 's4'...` on each server 1, 2 and 3

Replication events are represented in the common object naming manner: `originator.database.table`

When event is replicated from, say, S1 to S4 it will be applied to the replica of `x_1` on S4 as well as written to the binlog. Then that event will be replicated back to the S1. Each replication event is marked by its originator. S4 will see that certain event's originator is S1 and applies it to the corresponding database. When that event has been replicated back to the S1 it will see that he was an originator of the event and discard it. If certain event will be originated from S4 it will be applied by S1.

The whole setup isn't easy to maintain as far as each crash recovery will require the total reinitialization from the scratch. If you really want something like that you'd better look at the `mariadb/galera`.